# Extract html Class ID using python

Tags: python, html

This is probably dumb, but I was wondering if python can extract class ID from a html tag? The only reason I need it is that the class id keeps changing randomly every 24 hours, and I need to parse it later.
In this case I need the `FFVAD`

```
<img alt="SOME TEXT" class="FFVAD" decoding="auto" style="" sizes="293px" srcset="https://somewebsite.com/8669459880035221504_n.jpg">
```

Maybe there's a way of using beautifulsoup or even selenium? Since my script is using selenium

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_attribute()` method in selenium.

```
elem.get_attribute('class')    # FFVAD
```

Comment: That sounds good. But what If there's more html tags with different class ID's, for example: `<div class="v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w">` or `<div class="KL4Bh">`  etc, etc.  Then I would just need it from the `<img alt>` tag

Comment: @uzdisral I was assuming you've already selected the element you want (in this case the `img` tag). You can select the element first using one of the method described in [this page](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: @uzdisral Just in case you need to use the css selector, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) is a nice cheetsheet for that

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am reading the first page you posted, but it seems like it is all hardcoded in, as for the ID, or name etc. I guess I should have my question to be more specific. When I'm scraping all the images from instagram, let's say there is 200 of them. They all use the same IDclass. I need just to store the ID from the first img and parse it later in my script. Since it's randomly changing, and I would have to always update my script manually